# Codeigniter , 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Developers i have a website www.johntravelsonlinebooking.in.

when i try to login my site then it shows me the error message-

Not Found
The requested URL /dashboard/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Other developer said i am facing this problem for .htaccess or config.php file but i try too many time to fix this but every time i failed so anyone know about this.If yes then please help me please.

Comment: Are you missing index.php in the URL ?

Comment: its working: `http://www.johntravelsonlinebooking.in/index.php/dashboard/`

Comment: nice admin panel, love it, please change the credentials

Answer (score 3):

First of all, i have updated your question and removed username and password.

Your project is working fine, if you use `index.php`.

```
http://www.johntravelsonlinebooking.in/index.php/dashboard/
```

*Now, you need to change `.htaccess` as:*

**Example from [User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now change `index_page` as empty from your config file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In last, still facing the same issue than use `uri_protocol` as:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

After these changes, you can access the

```
http://www.johntravelsonlinebooking.in/dashboard/
```